# Error while testing my install for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, command-prompt

```
C:\windows\system32>rails new test_install
      create
      create  README.rdoc
      create  Rakefile
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
      create  app
      create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/mailers/.keep
      create  app/models/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/bundle
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  config
      create  config/routes.rb
      create  config/application.rb
      create  config/environment.rb
      create  config/secrets.yml
      create  config/environments
      create  config/environments/development.rb
      create  config/environments/production.rb
      create  config/environments/test.rb
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/initializers/assets.rb
      create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
      create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
      create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
      create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
      create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
      create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
      create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
      create  config/locales
      create  config/locales/en.yml
      create  config/boot.rb
      create  config/database.yml
      create  db
      create  db/seeds.rb
      create  lib
      create  lib/tasks
      create  lib/tasks/.keep
      create  lib/assets
      create  lib/assets/.keep
      create  log
      create  log/.keep
      create  public
      create  public/404.html
      create  public/422.html
      create  public/500.html
      create  public/favicon.ico
      create  public/robots.txt
      create  test/fixtures
      create  test/fixtures/.keep
      create  test/controllers
      create  test/controllers/.keep
      create  test/mailers
      create  test/mailers/.keep
      create  test/models
      create  test/models/.keep
      create  test/helpers
      create  test/helpers/.keep
      create  test/integration
      create  test/integration/.keep
      create  test/test_helper.rb
      create  tmp/cache
      create  tmp/cache/assets
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts
      create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
         run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies.....
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.3
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.3
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.3
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activejob 4.2.3
Using mime-types 2.6.2
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.3
Using activemodel 4.2.3
Using arel 6.0.3
Using activerecord 4.2.3
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using bundler 1.10.6
Installing byebug 6.0.2 with native extensions

LoadError: cannot load such file -- devkit.rb
An error occurred while installing byebug (6.0.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '6.0.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I used the command rails new test_install on command prompt; I don't know why but my online tutor asked me to write this command on command prompt and it returned an error. What's wrong here? And what does this command do? And is it neccsary for this command to run to install ruby on rails?

Note- I use my college wifi which blocks most of the servers is it the problem?

Comment: Can you show your gemfile

Comment: And for tutorials, you should visit http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: How to show a gem file?

Comment: copy paste you Gemfile which is created in your directory, in the questions, I guess the issue is the byebug version